# How it comes when values of map are different between to cluster point in hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I use hazelcast to store data in memory, and sometimes one point will lose connection to others, and the value of hazelcast's map may be different.
I want to know how it comes when the connection is rebuilt when the values in map are different.

Answer (score 1):

When network partitioning happens, your cluster might split into two and as you say, the values might differ as they run in parallel. After the clusters join again, split-brain recovery mechanism executes. Depending on the data structure you use, the data in both clusters merge according to the configured merge policy. I suggest reading [Split Brain Recovery](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.2/manual/html-single/index.html#split-brain-recovery) section of the Hazelcast manual for more detail.